# Scrapyd corrupting response?

Tags: python, scrapy, character-encoding, web-crawler, scrapyd

I'm trying to scrape a specific website. The code I'm using to scrape it is the same as that being used to scrape many other sites successfully.

However, the resulting `response.body` looks completely corrupt (segment below):

```
����)/A���(��Ե�e�)k�Gl�*�EI�
                             ����:gh��x@����y�F$F�_��%+�\��r1��ND~l""�54بN�:�FA��W
b� �\�F�M��C�o.�7z�Tz|~΢0��̔HgA�\���[��������:*i�P��Jpdh�v�01]�Ӟ_e�b߇��,�X��E, ��냬�e��Ϣ�5�Ϭ�B<p�A��~�3t3'>N=`
```

And as a result it is impossible to parse.

What is really confusing is that if I run `scrapy shell` on the same URL, everything works fine (the website's charset is utf-8)---which is leading me to believe this is caused by scrapyd.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

### SETTINGS.py

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

BOT_NAME = "[name]"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["[name].spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "[name].spiders"

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
# USER_AGENT = '[name] (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

CRAWLERA_MAX_CONCURRENT = 50
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = CRAWLERA_MAX_CONCURRENT
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = CRAWLERA_MAX_CONCURRENT

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 600
DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True

COOKIES_ENABLED = False  # Disable cookies (enabled by default)

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    "X-Crawlera-Profile": "desktop",
    "X-Crawlera-Cookies": "disable",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware": 200,
    "scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware": 300,
}
CRAWLERA_ENABLED = True
CRAWLERA_APIKEY = "KEY"

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "[name].pipelines.Export": 400,
}
# sentry dsn
SENTRY_DSN = "Key"

EXTENSIONS = {
    "[name].extensions.SentryLogging": -1,  # Load SentryLogging extension before others
}```
````

Comment: Could please add your code and settings?

Comment: @MuratDemir I've added the settings. The spider codebase is very large, so wouldn't be useful. I'm basically checking `response.body` which is corrupt (`response.encoding` is utf-8 as expected), so response.css(anything) fails.

Comment: Have you checked `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding`? And have you tried to get the url via curl - is it different?

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko It's `text/html; charset=utf-8`, and works fine with curl. It works fine even with `scrapy shell`.

Comment: @AimiHat I wonder if it's because of the middleware being used. I suggest to disable one by one in your config.

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko thanks :) see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Serhii's suggestion, I found that the issue was due to `"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"`: I accepted compressed sites but did not handle them in scrapy.

Adding `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression` or simply removing the `accept-encoding` line fixes the issue.